# How can I combine two datasets with the same schema in to one table?

Tags: postgis, sql, carto

I have two tables (in CartoDB/PostGIS) that are from two tiger shapefiles that have the exact same attributes, just in different counties. I want to combine them in to a single table, just appending the data from one to the other. What is the SQL call to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have two datyasets with the same attributes:

**test_points1**

[image]

and **test_points2**

[image]

you can combine them like this:

```
CREATE TABLE combined AS( 
    SELECT id, city, geom FROM test_points1
    UNION 
    SELECT id, city, geom FROM test_points2)
```

and the result is the **combined** table:

[image]

Comment: The UNION keyword will check to ensure that all records are unique (which is expensive). If you don't want then de-duped in the process, use UNION ALL instead.